# What does the "name" of a Keras metric do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Many Keras metrics `tf.keras.metrics.Mean`, `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy`, etc. have an optional property called `name`.

What is the use case for this property?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.metrics.Mean` is a class so it can be instantiated multiple times. The `name` attribute can be used to choose the name of each instance.

It is then an optional string parameter of the constructor.

Source: [Keras doc](https://keras.io/api/metrics/accuracy_metrics/#binaryaccuracy-class)

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the [Metrics](https://keras.io/api/metrics/) section :

> Usage with compile() & fit()
>
> The compile() method takes a metrics argument, which is a list of metrics:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=[
        metrics.MeanSquaredError(),
        metrics.AUC(),
    ]
)
```

> Metric values are displayed during fit() and logged to the History object returned by fit(). They are also returned by model.evaluate().
>
> Note that the best way to monitor your metrics during training is via TensorBoard.
>
> To track metrics under a specific name, you can pass the name argument to the metric constructor:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=[
        metrics.MeanSquaredError(name='my_mse'),
        metrics.AUC(name='my_auc'),
    ]
)
```

> All built-in metrics may also be passed via their string identifier (in this case, default constructor argument values are used, including a default metric name):

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=[
        'MeanSquaredError',
        'AUC',
    ]
)
```